# Installing an exhaust fan in place of a light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]

I am installing a new exhaust fan with 2 lights. The box where the switch goes, has a 2 wire and ground coming in to it. The black is hot. When the light would be turned on both the black and white became hot so the white was my return. I am installing a 3 toggle switch in its place. Can I just use the wires there or do I need to run new wires from a power source. I am confused. I am thinking I need to run anew line, but don’t get it. Why can’t I use the wires in the box? The diagram for the switch shows a black hot coming in and then 3 blacks going out to the fixture. Then it shows white coming back as a return. Where do I hook that up? The existing white? Or no. I’m confused about that part. Yes there is a ground.

---

[image]here is the picture of the old light fixture and box.

---

[image]once the power comes into the switch box I plan to run into three toggle switch. I am running new wires from the box to the exhaust fan and lights

Comment: Is replacing the existing /2 cable with something fatter an option?

Comment: What do you mean something fatter?  I need to trace the present wire back to a box where it is getting the power in the attic I believe. I haven’t figured that out yet.

Comment: "something fatter" means a cable with more wires in it, or even a conduit depending on how many wires you need

Comment: Gotcha. It is possible I believe. I purchased NM-B with 14/3 with a ground.

Comment: My issue is I believe the power coming in. Correct?  I need to change that wire so it has 3 wires and a ground. Correct?

Comment: You may need something bigger than a 14/3 even, given that you have a triple switch in play....

Comment: Something doesn't add up here -- is there another junction box in this circuit somewhere?

Comment: That’s what I’m kind of thinking. But I’m not positive.  May just bypass that junction box where the hot is coming from and run a new 14/3from a new power source/junction box if I can’t figure out which one it is. The black wire in the switch box is hot, but nothing is hot where the fixture is unless I throw the switch. So, I’m thinking there is.

Comment: Yeah, you may have to run new cables from a power source to the switch, then from the switch to the fan....

Comment: I will be running a new line 14/3 from a power source to the switch box. The power will then be in the switch box. I want to be able to turn each item on separately (fan, light, and night light).  That’s why I have a 3 toggle switch.  Next question then is how do I wire the switches?  I will be having a hot to the switches. Do I tie all white together and all grounds together. I’ll have 3 wires coming to the box. What are each for?  Hot, ground etc?

Answer (score 1):

## The choice is yours to make based on how much control you want.

### Do you need to control the lights separately from the fan?

(do you mind if the fan comes on every time the lights come on?)

**If no:**

Just wire all the black wires to your existing black wire, the whites to white, and the ground to green and you are done!

**If yes:**

You'll need to run another wire.

If you decide you need to run another wire you need to ask your self

### Do you need to control the lights independently from one another?

**If yes:**

Then you'll need to run 14/4 wire and 2 more switches. (instructions below)

**If no:**

Then you can use the 14/3 you bought, but will need an extra switch.

**Instruction for connecting new wire:**

1. Connect all neutrals in the fan/light box together with the neutral (white) of you newly run wire.
2. Connect the neutral wire directly to the neutral (white) in your switch box
3. Connect the green grounding wire to your copper or green wire of your newly run wire.
4. Connect the green (or copper) grounding wire of your new wire to the grounding wire in your switch box with an added jumper if required for your switch.
5. Connect each of your switches to your the hot wire in your switch box via jumper wires
6. Connect each switch then distributes power to one of the remaining colored wires  (and take note of the order)
7. Connect the other end of the wire to the desired device you want it to control